# Getting Page loading error after successful Plugin installation in Moodle

Tags: php, plugins, xampp, moodle

I have installed Moodle 3.7.1 with XAMPP. The installation had been successful and problem-free. I followed the below video for installation:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ov2dGoOBmSI&t=436s

Now my main objective is moodle plugin development. Since I am relatively new to this I was exploring plugins and trying to build a simple one first.

But whenever I am trying to install plugin (my own or from Moodle directory) I receive the SUCCESS message but then get 'Page Loading Error' and thereafter I am not able to go to any page

I found this thread on Moodle forums and have tried most of the solutions they offered.
https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=355930

I dont wish to work on older XAMPP version
My cache folder under Xampp's moodledata folder is empty and i tried clearing my browser cache and restarting the servers. 
But the issue still persists

Any ideas what maybe causing this? I have a feeling that its some kind of configuration issue but I dont know where to look and what to look for.

Comment: Mmm hard to say... During an installation of Moodle or a Moodle plugin changes are made to your DB and to your moodledata, so those two are the main suspects. You could try to purge caches from your CMD `php.exe admin/cli/purge_caches.php` and see if that helps. Also enable Moodle debug mode by adding to your `config.php`: `@error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT); @ini_set('display_errors', '1'); $CFG->debug = (E_ALL | E_STRICT); $CFG->debugdisplay = 1;`
and see if that gives you any extra information. Also review the apache and php error logs and see if there is any clue around.

Comment: I added the debugger code you provided and  I get this in the Console: `moodle-core-event: Global event published: FORM_ERROR
moodle-core-event: Global event published: BLOCK_CONTENT_UPDATED`
Any idea?

Comment: In the apache error.log I am getting thi message repeatedly. `[ssl:warn] [pid 21496:tid 532] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name`

Comment: mmmm if the SSL is not properly set yet or you are working against your localhost get sure you have set `$CFG->wwwroot` URL in your config.php to start with http instead of https. You said you are getting JS errors in your browser's developer console? That's interesting, that necessarily means at some point a part of the page is being printed, at least the headers. It could help if I could see your `config.php` settings and a screenshot and URL of your "screen of death" view.

Comment: FYI after a successful Moodle installation or upgrade, there are some extra forms and steps you usually have to go through. In the case of the installation one of them is the admin user setup form, in installations and upgrade its also very common to have to review plugin settings defaults (a big form with many plugin settings all put together). Was your installation stuck in some of these steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help. It took me alot of installation and uninstallations but finally when I downloaded the full Windows installer package--it worked. 
I guess it was some kind of deeprooted version conflict between xampp and moodle or some configuration issue.